# Songplay (no.3)

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, music

I have another simple `Songplay` riddle for you! Good luck to you all!

> Babe you're just like candy,
>
> Lips of yours divine.
>
> See you've got me thirsty,
>
> Each and every, time you whine.

---

### What is the song and who is it by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this

> Hooked on a Feeling, by BJ Thomas/Blue Swede/David Hasselhoff?

Comment: Thats what i get when i put those lines in google!

Comment: yeah, this one is preeetty close to the actual lyrics...